# Hide add to cart for Guest User in Magento

Tags: php, magento, hide, cart

I got some code while searching for hide add to cart button at category products but i am not able to set this below code to my given `List.phtml`, Please guide me.

Now we will hide the ‘Add to Cart’ button on category list page. Open /app/design/frontend/default/themeXXX/template/catalog/product/list.phtml file and look for the following code:

```
<?php
if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
    echo '<span class="login_for_details" style="float:left"><strong>Login to Add to Cart</strong></span>';
} else { ?>
```

My website list.phtml

```
<?php if ($product->isSaleable()) : ?>
    <?php  if ( !($product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasOptions($product) || $product->isGrouped()) ) :  ?>
        <?php if(!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)):?>
            <form id="addtocart_form_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" action="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="qty-field">
            <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
            <div class="qty-holder">
                <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty_<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $product->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
                <div class="qty-changer">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_inc"><i class="icon-up-dir"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty_dec"><i class="icon-down-dir"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if (!Mage::getStoreConfig("ajaxcart/addtocart/enablecategory", $code)) :?>
            </form>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Are you creating separate module for this? or make changes in core code?

Comment: I wanted to change in core code. Please suggest me how to use this.

Answer (score 0):

If your changing in your core code then add the below code in your `List.phtml`

```
<?php $session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session', array('name' => 'frontend')); ?>  
<?php if($session->isLoggedIn()) { ?>  
    //Your Add to Cart Button Html  
<?php } else { ?>  
    // Your Login to Add to Cart Html  
<?php } ?>
```

Put the above code everywhere on your frontend where your products are displaying.